# Cerebot 32MX4 PMOD connections

Tags: microchip, mplab

I was working with my Microprocessor project on a Digilent Cerebot 32MX4 board. I need to use 4 PMODS(LEDS,Seven Segment Display,Push Switches,Buttons) for the project. I was able to connect three of them to PORTE(JA), PORTB(JJ) and PORTG(JB,JC). But i have problem with the fourth PMOD. I dont know where to connect the fourth PMOD. Are there any PORT`s available to connect the fourth PMOD.